# How to get Basic Authentication Information in a Firefox Extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, basic-authentication

I'm coding a Firefox extension and want to get Basic Authentication information for a website (or for the current document).

How can I get Basic Authentication Information in a Firefox Extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find an exact answer and don't have time to experiment now, but it seems that the only way is to manually examine headers using [NsIHttpChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsIHttpChannel).

EDIT:
Ok, I've found [nsIHttpAuthManager](http://www.xulplanet.com/references/xpcomref/ifaces/nsIHttpAuthManager.html):

> This service provides access to cached HTTP authentication user credentials (domain, username, password) for sites visited during the current browser session.

Looks like exactly what you need.

Comment: I assume for this I have to carry out a test request, but it should be already in Firefox's memory. I'm trying to avoid extra requests actually.

Comment: I didn't find any exception working with user credentials, but while looking for it, found nsIHttpAuthManager interface.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some sample code for using [nsIHttpAuthManager](http://www.oxymoronical.com/experiments/apidocs/interface/nsIHttpAuthManager):

Instantiate the component:

```
var proxyAuthenticationComponent = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/http-auth-manager;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpAuthManager);
```

Set the information:

```
proxyAuthenticationComponent.setAuthIdentity('http','192.168.0.1',80,"basic","Some Realm","","","username","password");
```

Get the information:

```
var domain = {}; //Will contain {value: ""}
var username = {}; //Will contain {value: "username"}
var password = {}; //Will contain {value: "password"}
proxyAuthenticationComponent.getAuthIdentity('http','192.168.0.1',80,"basic","Some Realm","",domain,username,password);
```

I used this in a Thunderbird extension.
Hope this help.